# How can I deploy my app from github to Railway

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, bootstrap-4

I am at a loss as to why I am getting these errors.
Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about.

[image]

Can you please make sense of what these errors are telling me?

I tried to change the code on app.js file so it would make refer to local hosts.

My URL is https://web-production-68cf.up.railway.app/
but all I see is the static part of this web app.

Comment: Please do not expect others to debug live code. Instead, edit the question to include a text-based [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.